# MS ACCESS - How to set the split form width size on SplitFormSize property

Tags: forms, ms-access, split, properties, width

I have a split form and i tried to modify the `SplitFormSize` in the property window.
If i enter the value of 13cm it sets only the height and not the width..

How can i change the width size?
should i do that in VBA? How?

Answer (score 0):

Aspect of split form is it opens to full width of app window. Cannot be managed in Properties.

If db is set for Overlapping Windows, manage width of form (not popup) with MoveSize method, like:

`DoCmd.MoveSize , , 7 * 1440`

Width is set in TWIPS -- 1440 per inch; 567 per cm

Comment: It works for me. What is the exact code you attempted? Cannot be a popup form.

Comment: i created a new splitform from scratch and add just on Form_Open event what you posted and it doesn't work..

Comment: Can't explain that. Still works for me. Did you set breakpoint and debug? Does the event run?